# tables for managing appointments

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Can somebody help with the DB design, where I want to have an appointments table (`appointment id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `time`), however this appoinment could be a follow-up to a previous one, and I want to maintain the link to the that appointmnet.  I could have 'appointment_type' as one more attribute, however how would I know which is the primary appointment, versus a follow-on appointment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a foreign key self-reference; I would say simply add a (nullable integer) field `previous_appointment_id` (and maybe `next_appointment_id` also if you need the link to go two ways).

This way you can also tell the *type* of appointment by checking whether `previous_appointment_id` is null.

Comment: Thanks a lot dbaseman, I guess previous_appointment_id should suffice that way for the next_appointment - the current_appointment_id will become value for the previous_appointment.